# Header file not found but only for device builds, not simulator builds

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, file-not-found

When I updated my Xcode to 7.1.1 it started to show the message that the specific header file is not found but the header file is there.
And when I build for the simulator it doesn't show this message.

In Simulator Works:

[image]

In Device doesn`t:
[image]

And the most awkward is that I create a single view aplication with nothing and runs on device.

The Message shows:

```
/Users/gabrielrodrigues/Desktop/puc-vc/PUC VC/PUC VC-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: error: 'MMDrawerController.h' file not found
#import "MMDrawerController.h"
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/gabrielrodrigues/Desktop/puc-vc/PUC VC/PUC VC-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: Check the "header search path" and "framework search path" build settings. Make sure you don't have different paths for different types of builds.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, thx for edition of the post and help me, look this picture http://imgur.com/MFMcBLe here is my pod project, the library that are not found are the same patch in header search file for debug and release

Comment: @rmaddy I don't found the solution for this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't need to use the `Bridging-header.h` anymore cuz I'm using cocoa pods that implements a support for this situation, for solve I just delete the file and insert in the views:

```
import MMDrawerController
```

Like a normal Swift library.

[Support of CocoaPods](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/)