# Compiling for device, swift header file not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Recently added first swift file to large obj-c project.  Compile and run in simulator is fine.  Attempt to compile and run for a device and I get a file not found error on the obj-c compiler generated swift header file (aka Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name ending with -swift.h)

I have confirmed (at least to my knowledge) that project settings are correct and can see the file in the (derived data) file system for debug / simulator builds but nothing else.

Have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098696/import-swift-class-in-objective-c-mymodule-swift-h-file-not-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168529/header-file-not-found-but-only-for-device-builds-not-simulator-builds) but have not helped. Using xCode8 GM

Comment: I have the same problem, and its driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

The problem corrected itself when I

- Did a clean (have done many times before)
- Built for "Generic" iOS device (success)
- Closed and restarted Xcode
- Built for Device

go figure..

[Edit] and if this doesn't help .. try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062618/swift-to-objective-c-header-not-created-in-xcode-6?rq=1) I just found for more ideas