# MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, mwphotobrowser

I only get this error when I build on my device (iPhone 6 and 5s). It popped up randomly today when I pod installed Firebase/Core. I've deleted it since. However, it works fine on the simulator. 
Can anyone help me with a fix?

Comment: Take a look at this question [Header file not found but only for device builds, not simulator builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168529/header-file-not-found-but-only-for-device-builds-not-simulator-builds)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I fixed the error. Apparently it was being caused by Firebase's plist file which I forgot to delete when I removed Firebase/Core from my podfile.